# ListView in Android does not populate

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

ALL,
I have a little problem.
I am trying to create a following layout for my application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/output" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    layout_margin="1dp" 
    android:textSize="18sp" 
    android:text=" " 
     >
    </TextView>
    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/next"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="340dp"
      android:src="@drawable/next"
    />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/next"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="340dp"
        android:src="@drawable/save"
    />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/filenames"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:layout_below="@id/output"
        android:layout_above="@+id/save"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in my source I use following:

```
    test = new ArrayList<String>();
    test.add( "a" );
    test.add( "b" );
    test.add( "c" );
    lv = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.filenames );
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, test );
    lv.setAdapter( adapter );
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled( true );
    lv.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            m_fileclicked = (String) lv.getItemAtPosition( position );
        }
    });
```

The problem is that I can see the buttons and the text, but the list view is black (i.e. empty).

The code is using the Acivity, not ListActivity.

I looked around - there are at least 3 examples here on how to populate the list view when using the activity, but they all use some "crazy" layouts.

I just need to display a simple strings.

Can someone please help?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you elaborate how your layout is looking like.

Answer (score 1):

You code looks OK to me.

I'd personally simplify your layout first (purely as a test) in case your `ListView` is being hidden or not expanding correctly in the `RelativeLayout`.

I'd place the `ListView` in a simple `LinearLayout` as a test and just have your `ListView` stretch height and width with nothing else in the layout:

```
  <ListView
        android:id="@+id/filenames"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

If the `ListView` then displays correctly, you know the issue is with the `RelativeLayout` code as opposed to the binding of the adapter.

I guess you're binding in the `onCreate()` method too?

Comment: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
   <TextView android:id="@+id/output" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
  android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
  android:scaleType="center"
  android:gravity="center_horizontal"
  layout_margin="1dp" 
  android:textSize="18sp" 
  android:text=" ">

Comment: <ListView
  android:id="@+id/filenames"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
  android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
 />
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

Comment: <ImageView
   android:id="@+id/next"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="340dp"
   android:src="@drawable/next"
   />
   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/save"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/next"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="340dp"
    android:src="@drawable/save"
   />
   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
`code`

Comment: but I can't see anything. No buttons and no text.

Answer (score 1):

First you check  your button id **output** is that **next**?

```
    android:layout_below="@id/output"
    android:layout_above="@+id/save"
```

another thing **m_fileclicked**  where you declared it. Is that string or not. please correct that.

**You can try this simple example:**

```
public class ListExample extends Activity
{
 private ListView list;
 private String countries[]={"Nepal","India","China","Norway","germany"};
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
    {
   super.onCreate(icicle);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
   list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
   list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,    countries));
  list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
  list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
      AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(ListExample.this);
      builder.setTitle(" List Item Demo");
      builder.setMessage("Your Selected Item is = "+list.getItemAtPosition(Position));
      builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
    builder.show();
         }
      });
    }
 }
```

you xml file only you can listview add and which has name ListView01.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have clear knowledge on RelativeLayout attributes.This layout provides the designer to design the layout as they need. This layout provides such kind of features for developers. Follow these links

http://android-pro.blogspot.com/2010/03/relative-layout.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html

Answer (score 0):

Your `TextView` fills the parent's height and your listview is placed below this textview. I think that is the problem. Your `@id/output` text view should `layout_height="wrap_content"`.

```
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/output" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

### Update

Set the listview's background to red so you can clearly distinguish it(just test.) 
Please REMOVE `layout_marginTop` from the `<ImageView>`s and use `layout_alignParentBottom="true"` instead.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/output" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" // should wrap content
    ......./>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/next" 
        .......
        .......  // REMOVE MARGIN TOP
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" //align parent bottom
    />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/save" 
        .......
        .......  // REMOVE MARGIN TOP
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  //align parent bottom
    />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/filenames"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        .......... />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is there an attribute for the TextView which says: "Make this TextView n pixels height"? Or maybe set the margin from the bottom of the phone?

Comment: Also, I just tried to use "wrap_content", but without success. I still don't see anything where the ListView should be.

Comment: Change the listview bg and add a snapshot of it in your question. Also update the layout xml in the question.